# Swift UI - HostingController adds unwanted navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am attempting to integrate SwiftUI into my project, and I am currently using a storyboard which is launched via my app delegate with the following code:

```
_rootNavigiationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
_rootNavigiationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:StoryboardLoginRegister bundle:nil];
BasicInformation *basicInfo = (BasicInformation *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"basic-info"];
[self.rootNavigiationController setViewControllers:@[basicInfo]];
```

So essentially my App delegate is in objective-c and the windows root controller is a UINavigation controller.

My BasicInformation class looks like:

```
class BasicInfo: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBSegueAction func addSwiftUi(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
        let BasicInfoUI = BasicInfo_UI();
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: BasicInfoUI);
        hostingController?.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true;
        return hostingController;
    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

And the Swift UI for the basic information is the following:

```
struct BasicInfo_UI: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var isPrivate: Bool = true
    @State var notificationsEnabled: Bool = false
    @State private var previewIndex = 0
    var previewOptions = ["Always", "When Unlocked", "Never"]

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("PROFILE")) {
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                Toggle(isOn: $isPrivate) {
                    Text("Private Account")
                }
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("NOTIFICATIONS")) {
                Toggle(isOn: $notificationsEnabled) {
                    Text("Enabled")
                }
                Picker(selection: $previewIndex, label: Text("Show Previews")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< previewOptions.count) {
                        Text(self.previewOptions[$0])
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("ABOUT")) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Version")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("2.2.1")
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Perform an action here...")
                }) {
                    Text("Reset All Settings")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BasicInfo_UI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BasicInfo_UI()
    }
}
```

My only issue is i can't seem to figure out why i have a navigation bar at the top of the UI in my app

[image: Unwanted navigation bar]

Hoping somebody can explain to me why exactly there is a navigation bar at the top of my controller event though i've explicitly set navigationbarhidden to true in multiple places in my app

Comment: Filed a bug, this should not happen. (12183054)

Answer (score 7):

Try to hide navigation bar by SwiftUI explicitly, like

```
Form {

  // ... other code

}
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this tip. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Nope. That just doesn't work, at least with iOS 15.7.
I'm going to file a bug. Embedded SwiftUI view should not control the visibility  of its  embedding view controller.

Comment: Yeah, this works fine. But unfortunately not for iOS 15. @Martin did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

After long attempts, I have the same behavior in my UIKit project and SwiftUI Views with `UIHostingController` as with just UIKit.

In my storyboard, the `UIHostingController` is embedded in the `NavigationController` and this in turn is connected to the `UITabBarController`.

The first thing to do is to uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar" in the Attributes Inspector of the `NavigationController`.

In the SwiftUI View I have the list in the `NavigationView` with the modifier `.navigationBarTitle("ViewTitle", displayMode: .large)` and the next SwiftUI Views without `NavigationView` and the list with `.navigationBarTitle ("SecondViewTitle", displayMode: .inline)` modifier.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question is about SwiftUI and not UIKit. Recommend deletion.

Comment: This will produce a visible glich: the navigation bar will be displayed during the push animation, then hidden on animation stop.